# Computer in infinite reboot loop after removing Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, reboot, lenovo-laptop

I just removed Linux from my laptop, by deleting its folders ("deepin" and "ubuntu") from the UEFI directory. After that, I tried rebooting, but now it's stuck in a boot loop. The Lenovo logo pops on but then flashes to a message I am unable to read because it flashes away and reboots immediately...

**EDIT**

Found out what the message is. It says:

```
System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults
Reset System
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got into the BIOS, turned out that I just needed to hold down the FN key while pressing F2. I checked the settings, didn't change *anything* and exited. It suddenly booted to Windows 10...